# Rebind a rotated array with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I want to rotate back and forth (carrousel) an array on pressing the according buttons. The below code does that exactly.

Now I asked my self is this the correct way it should be done. I mean the way how I rebind the result from the rotation function.

with the self.list(myNewArray) I throw away the former array. Is this correct?

```
       $(function () {

            Array.prototype.rotateLeft = function () {

                var first = this.shift();
                this.push(first);
                return this;
            }
            Array.prototype.rotateRight = function () {
                var last = this.pop();
                this.unshift(last);
                return this;
            }

            var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

            function NumberViewModel(numbers) {
                var self = this;
                self.list = ko.observableArray(numbers);
                self.rotateLeft = function () {
                    self.list(self.list().rotateLeft());
                };
                self.rotateRight = function () {
                    self.list(self.list().rotateRight());
                };
            }
            var vm = new NumberViewModel(numbers);
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button data-bind="click: rotateLeft">rotate left</button>
    <button data-bind="click: rotateRight">rotate right</button>
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'listTempl', foreach: list }">
    </ul>
    <script id="listTempl" type="text/html">
        <li style="float:left;list-style:none;padding-left:5px;font-size:30px;" data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds good since you update your list only once. I'd give a look at splice, and slice. You can do atomic changes. Like slicing the whole list except the index you want and insert it before or after to rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It s good but not perfect.
You better do that :

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function NumberViewModel(numbers) {
    var self = this;
    self.list = ko.observableArray(numbers);
    self.rotateLeft = function () {
        var item = self.list.shift();
        self.list.push(item);
    };
    self.rotateRight = function () {           
        var item = self.list.pop();
        self.list.unshift(item);
    };
}
var vm = new NumberViewModel(numbers);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The difference between our code is that you modify the inner array of the observableArray and you set it the result. That cause a refresh the whole observableArray.

I think it is much more better to modify directly the observableArray.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rCkCV/)